# How to apply Dark mode for xls file using WKWebView?

Tags: javascript, css, objective-c, ios13

I want to apply dark mode for every document type so dark mode working fine with .doc file but not working for XLS file because xls file has many tabs so not applied in every tab.
So can anyone help me out?

```
-(void) webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {    
        NSString *cssString = @" @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { body {background-color: black;color: white;}}";
        NSString *javascriptString = @"var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '%@'; document.head.appendChild(style)";
        NSString *javascriptWithCSSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:javascriptString, cssString];
       [webView evaluateJavaScript:javascriptWithCSSString completionHandler:nil];    
}
```

Comment: anyone can try to help?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to invert all element style like this (with re-invert for images) in css :

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    html{
        filter: invert(1)  hue-rotate(.5turn);
    }
    img {
        filter: invert(1)  hue-rotate(.5turn);
    }
}
```